# Apache and .htaccess, force download of all directories

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have lots of directories, each one with lots of images.

```
/root
    /dir1
        img1
        img2
        ...
    ...
```

I'd like to force download when I click on the upper directory /root. Is this possible?
Or how should I do?

Comment: Question: download what?

Comment: Sorry, if I click on /root... I'd like to download all the internal dirs... or If I click on dir1, it should download dir1.... I guess this is possible making ZIP archives...

Comment: I don't think you can do that with apache, you have to rewrite it to php [or ...]  and make a zip file on fly! and send it to user!

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34758866/257319